# Equivalence between norms on interpolation spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, interpolation, interpolation-theory

Let $X_1,X_2$ be *disjoint* (except for the $0$ vector) Banach subspaces of a topological vector space $X$, i.e.:
$$
X_1\cap X_2 = \{0\}.
$$
Define a norms on the space
$
X_1 + X_2
$ by
$$
\|f\|_A\triangleq \max\{\|f_1\|_{X_1},\|f_2\|_{X_2}\}.
$$
$$
\|f\|_B\triangleq \inf\{\|f_1\|_{X_1}+\|f_2\|_{X_2}:\, f=f_1+f_2, f_1 \in X_1,f_2 \in f_2\}.
$$
Are these two norms equivalent on $X_1+X_2$?

It seems to me to be the case, since all norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the disjointnes condition $X_1\cap X_2 =\{0\}$ essentially means that $\|\cdot\|_A$ factors through $\ell^{\infty}_n$ ie:
$$
\|f\|_A = \|\|f_1\|_{X_1},\|f_2\|_{X_2}\|_{\ell^{\infty}}...
$$
But maybe I'm missing something?...

Comment: You are correct, i think. Any element $x \in X_1 + X_2$ admits a unique decomposition as two elements $x = x_1 + x_2$. Your norms are the $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$ direct sums of $X_1$ and $X_2$.